# In which database table does UserManager.CreateAsync save data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In which database table does UserManager.CreateAsync save data? I have also added properties in Applicationuser. Are those additional properties also dumped in the same table?

Comment: It is in `AspNetUsers` table.

Comment: @RosdiKasim Thanks. I looked into that table but did not find any entries I entered. Also, if i try to register again, it says the user already exists.

Comment: @bill, you should include more information on how your context is setup, connection string and so on...